# Right way to scan all files / directories

Tags: delphi

I have some application that needs to scan all files trying to recognize some particular stuff. But I'm really in doubt if this is the best way to scan all units/directories/files in the computer. Here's the code:
To check if the unit is a fixed volume I'm doing:

```
procedure TForm1.MapUnits;
var
  Drive: char;
begin
  for Drive:= 'A' to 'Z' do
    begin
      case GetDriveType(PChar(Drive + ':/')) of
        DRIVE_FIXED:
          MapFiles(Drive + ':\');
      end;
    end;
end;
```

The MapFiles is:

```
procedure TForm1.MapFiles(DriveUnit: string);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  DirList: TStringList;
  IsFound: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  DirList := TStringList.Create;
  IsFound:= FindFirst(DriveUnit + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0;
  while IsFound do
    begin
      if ((SR.Attr and faArchive) <> 0) and (SR.Name[1] <> '.') then
        begin
          ScanFile(DriveUnit + SR.Name);
        end;
      if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (SR.Name[1] <> '.') then
        begin
          DirList.Add(DriveUnit + SR.Name);
        end;
      IsFound := FindNext(SR) = 0;
    end;
  FindClose(SR);
  // Scan the list of subdirectories
  for i := 0 to DirList.Count - 1 do
    MapFiles(DirList[i] + '\');
  DirList.Free;
end;
```

Please, note this method I'm using adding the subdir list to a TStringList and after finishing all the main directories, I do recall in MapFiles but now passing the sub-dir. Is this ok?
And to open the files found(ScanFile) I'm doing:

```
procedure TForm1.ScanFile(FileName: string);
var
  i, aux: integer;
  MyFile: TFileStream;
  AnsiValue, Target: AnsiString;
begin
  if (POS('.exe', FileName) = 0) and (POS('.dll', FileName) = 0) and
      (POS('.sys', FileName) = 0) then
    begin
      try
        MyFile:= TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
      except on E: EFOpenError do
        MyFile:= NIL;
      end;
      if MyFile <> NIL then
      try
        SetLength(AnsiValue, MyFile.Size);
        if MyFile.Size>0 then
          MyFile.ReadBuffer(AnsiValue[1], MyFile.Size);
        for i := 1 to Length(AnsiValue) do
          begin //Begin the search..
             //here I search my particular stuff in each file...
          end;
      finally
        MyFile.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

So, I'm doing this the correct way? Thank you!

Comment: @RBA that doesn't seem to be the same kind of search.

Comment: Did you encounter some specific problem or you would like your code to be reviewed? Also hint: never ever pass strings arguments by value, especially if you are doing recursion. Also: you have to check and ignore `'..'` directories encountered.

Comment: @FreeConsulting The `SR.Name[1] <> '.'` traps those. As well as directories named `'...'` and so on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a code review. Please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comments:

1. You test twice for `SR.Name[1] <> '.'`. You should be able to do that once.
2. Your test for `SR.Name[1] <> '.'` is flawed. Yes it will find `'.'` and `'..'`, but it will also find `'.svn'` and `'.....'` and so on. You need to test for equality with both `'.'` and `'..'`.
3. Rather than `*.*`, it is idiomatic to use `*`.
4. You ought to protect `DirList` with a `try/finally`.
5. Your program will take forever to run.
6. The program will almost certainly fail with memory fragmentation. And likely out right failure if it is a 32 bit program and you encounter any large files. You should avoid loading entire files into memory. Just read small pieces at a time.
7. `ReadBuffer` may throw exceptions. Are you ready for them? You might be better off putting your `try/except` around the entire read operation, and not just the file open.
8. Your attempt to find files with particular extensions is flawed. For instance, would you regard this file as being an executable file: *MyFile.exe.blahblah.txt*? No, I did not think so. The right way to test for extension is like so: `SameText(ExtractFileExt(FileName), Extension)`.